# ORMLite: Query empty foreign field

Tags: android, ormlite

I have two entities: EntityA and EntityB. EntityB has a foreign field of EntityA:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign=true, columnName=ENT_A_NAME)
private EntityA entityA;
```

Now I want to query all entries of EntityB where EntityA is null. So I've made the following query:

```
bDao.queryBuilder().where().isNull(EntityB.Ent_A_NAME).prepare();
```

If I execute the query I get an empty result set back.

If I execute `queryAll()` I see that the entries of EntityB have always an associated Order-Object with all values set to null/0.

How can I execute my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure @Toni4780.  The following test case works for me.  I don't see anything that you are doing wrong.

In the table for `EntityB`, [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) actually stores the *id* of the `EntityA` so I am wondering if it is null or 0.  Have you tried the following?

```
bDao.queryBuilder().where().eq(EntityB.Ent_A_NAME, 0).prepare();
```

or both:

```
bDao.queryBuilder().where().isNull(EntityB.Ent_A_NAME).
    or().eq(EntityB.Ent_A_NAME, 0).prepare();
```

Here's my unit test code that works:

```
Dao<Order, Integer> orderDao =
    DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, Order.class);
TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Order.class);
int numOrders = 10;
for (int orderC = 0; orderC < numOrders; orderC++) {
    Order order = new Order();
    order.val = orderC;
    assertEquals(1, orderDao.create(order));
}
List<Order> results = orderDao.queryBuilder().where()
    .isNull(Order.ACCOUNT_FIELD_NAME).query();
assertNotNull(results);
assertEquals(numOrders, results.size());
```

Comment: Ok. Now it got it working using BOTH isNull() and eq().(..,0). The strange thing that some (2) items got returned with isNull() and the other (5) items got returned with eq(). A sidenote: I really like ormlite. Keep up the good work :)